# Excel 2007 Compare two columns in same row

Tags: excel, function, formula

I have c2 with list names starting with state abbreviations. Then I have e2 with state abbreviations.

I need to input a formula into b2 that compares for the same row only and returns a matched or unmatched value.

I had this figured out already, but I can't seem to get it working again.

Comment: `I had this figured out already, but I can't seem to get it working again.` - show us please what have you tried already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

**=IF(LEFT(C2,2)=LEFT(E2,2),"match","unmatch")**

Comment: This did it! I swear that this is exactly what I had, but apparently I had uses too many parenthesis sets.